# What should be the minimum value when the two threads are executed concurrently

Tags: operating-systems, parallel-computing, threads, mutual-exclusion

```
int count=0;
void *thfunc()
{
    int ctr=0;
    for(ctr=0;ctr<100;ctr++)
    count++;
}
```

If *thfunc() is executed by two threads concurrently in a uniprocessor system, what will be the minimum value of count when both threads complete their execution? Assume that count++ is performed by using three instructions:(1) Read value of count from memory to a CPU register R,(2) Increment R,(3) Store the value in memory.

(a) 200

(b) 2

(c) 100

(d) None of the above

According to me, the answer should be 100. I cant find any execution sequence in which the count value can go down below 100. But my manual says that the answer is 2.

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Also, please explain how the answer 2 is obtained?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a tricky interleaving. `R1,R2` denote the independent logical registers used by the threads, while `count` is the shared variable in memory.

- Thread 1 starts its first iteration, performing only a read. `count=0, R1=0, R2=?`
- Thread 2 performs 99 iterations. `count=99, R1=0, R2=99`
- Thread 1 completes its first iteration (increment and write). `count=1, R1=1, R2=99`
- Thread 2 starts iteration #100, performing only a read. `count=1, R1=1, R2=1`
- Thread 1 performs the other 99 iterations. `count=100, R1=100, R2=1`
- Thread 2 completes its iteration #100 (increment and write). `count=2, R1=100, R2=2`
- Both threads now exit, having completed their execution.

So, the sequence is something like

```
rX = read by thread X
iX = local increment by thread X
wX = write by thread X

r1,
r2,i2,w2,r2,i2,w2,...,r2,i2,w2,  (99 full iterations)
i1,w1,
r2,
r1,i1,w1,r1,i1,w1,...,r1,i1,w1,  (99 full iterations)
i2,w2
```

Comment: Hi @Chi, can you please elaborate a bit more from line 4? It's difficult to follow after that....

Comment: @AbhilashMishra In line 4, thread 2 has to perform its last loop iteration. It starts reading count into its local register R2. Before it increments and store it in memory, thread, thread 1 performs 99 iterations (line 5). Can you point out the part where you need more help?